# Error when registering a new client in the base using MVVM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Good morning everyone, I'm taking this "InvalidOperationException: The value of 'Customer.CustomerId' is unknown when trying to save changes.
" in my application when I try to save the client in the base to receive its ID to pass in the second item of the ViewModel.
I'm using Asp.Net Core 5

```
public class Cliente
{
    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
   
    [Display(Name = "Fantasia")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string Fantasia { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Inscrição Estadual")]
    public string IE { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CPF ou CNPJ")]
    public string Cpf_Cnpj { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo Pessoa")]
    public string Tipo_Pessoa { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o seu endereço")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Endereço")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Numero")]
    public string Numero { get; set; }

    [Display(Name =  "Informe o seu Complemento")]
    public string Complemento { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o seu CEP")]
    [Display(Name = "CEP")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 8)] 
    public string Cep { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
    public string Cidade { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    [Display(Name = "Estado")]
    public string Estado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public bool Situacao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Segmento")]
    public string Segmento { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Porte")]
    public string Porte { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Contato> Contato { get; set; }
}
 public class Contato
{
    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ContatoId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o sobrenome")]
    [Display(Name = "Sobrenome")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cargo")]
    public string Cargo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Setor")]
    public string Setor { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o seu Email")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o seu telefone")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    [Display(Name = "Telefone")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o seu Celular")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Celular { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Usuário")]
    public int? UsuarioId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UsuarioId")]
    public virtual Usuario Usuarios { get; set; }

    
    public int? ClienteId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
    public virtual Cliente Clientes { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
 public class ClienteViewModel
{
    public Cliente cliente { get; set; }


    public Contato contato { get; set; }

}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Cadastrar(ClienteViewModel clienteViewModel)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            Models.Cliente cliente = new Models.Cliente
            {
                Nome = clienteViewModel.cliente.Nome,
                Tipo_Pessoa = clienteViewModel.cliente.Tipo_Pessoa,
                Cpf_Cnpj = clienteViewModel.cliente.Cpf_Cnpj,
                Fantasia = clienteViewModel.cliente.Fantasia,
                IE = clienteViewModel.cliente.IE,
                Porte = clienteViewModel.cliente.Porte,
                Segmento = clienteViewModel.cliente.Segmento,
                Cep = clienteViewModel.cliente.Cep,
                Endereco = clienteViewModel.cliente.Endereco,
                Numero = clienteViewModel.cliente.Numero,
                Complemento = clienteViewModel.cliente.Complemento,
                Bairro = clienteViewModel.cliente.Bairro,
                Cidade = clienteViewModel.cliente.Cidade,
                Estado = clienteViewModel.cliente.Estado,
                Situacao = true
            };

            _clienteRespository.Cadastrar(cliente);

            Contato contato = new Contato
            {
                Nome = clienteViewModel.contato.Nome,
                Sobrenome = clienteViewModel.contato.Sobrenome,
                Telefone = clienteViewModel.contato.Telefone,
                Celular = clienteViewModel.contato.Celular,
                Email = clienteViewModel.contato.Email,
                Cargo = clienteViewModel.contato.Cargo,
                Setor = clienteViewModel.contato.Setor,
                ClienteId = cliente.ClienteId,
                Clientes = cliente
            };

            Models.Usuario usuario = new Models.Usuario()
            {
                Nome = contato.Nome,
                Sobrenome = contato.Sobrenome,
                Email = contato.Email,
                Telefone = contato.Celular,
                Cargo = contato.Cargo,
                Setor = contato.Setor,
                PerfilId = _helpers.createPerfilSuperAdministradorCliente(cliente.ClienteId).PerfilClienteId,
                Senha = contato.Email,
                Status = true
            };
            _usuarioRespository.Cadastrar(usuario);

            clienteViewModel.contato.UsuarioId = usuario.UsuarioId;


            _clienteRespository.Cadastrar(cliente.ClienteId, contato);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Repository

```
 public void Cadastrar(Cliente cliente)
    {
        _context.Add(cliente);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Cadastrar(int ClienteId, Contato contato)
    {
        contato.ClienteId = ClienteId;
        _context.Add(contato);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to fix ALL your repositories

```
public void Cadastrar(Cliente cliente)
    {
        _context.Set<Cliente>().Add(cliente);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Cadastrar(int ClienteId, Contato contato)
    {
        contato.ClienteId = ClienteId;
        _context.Set<Contato>.Add(contato);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```